# How to debug a dockerized django in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, docker-compose

I am facing problems integrating the VS Code debugger into my project which is dockerized.

About my project, it was not made by me, so as much I entered before, I am facing some challenges with Docker, but also learning. We use this command to access the local host:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```

And this is the [docker-compose.dev](http://docker-compose.dev) which is here as file:

```
/.vscode
/config
/example_app
...
.dockerignore
.gitignore
docker-compose.dev #The one who we up
```

And this is the file

```
volumes:
  postgres_data_test: {}
  hashes: {}
  product_api_root: {}

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./backups:/backups
    ports:
      - "8889:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=example
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - hashes:/hashes
      - product_api_root:/product-api-root
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=example
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://example:example@postgres:5432/example
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.local
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6
```

I have been trying two options to debug it

#### First option

This is the one which VS Code itself documented which is configuring the `tasks.json` and `launch.json` inside the `.vscode` folder:

For reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python

This is the `launch.json` that I tried (I tried a lot but this was the last one, the others I tried before did not work too):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
      ],
      "port": 8000,
      "host": "localhost",
      "preLaunchTask": "docker-compose up",
      "postDebugTask": "docker-compose down",
      "justMyCode": false,
      "django": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "docker-compose up",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "docker-compose up",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to use the debugger by clicking F5 I get an error:

```
The preLaunchTask 'docker-compose up' terminated with exit code 1.
```

And this also happened on my before tries.

#### Second option

I tried to use the extension Remote Containers or Dev Containers.

1. I open my project
2. I try to attach Django container
3. A new window opens
4. I try to open my project folder
5. Infinite loading

I also tried to open a new vs code window with no folders:

1. Click F1 and ‘Open folder in container’
2. Try to open my project folder
3. Get the error “Workspace does not exist”

For reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

So, I could use any of them, I just need one that works.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to check what's happening could be to run `docker exec -it $(docker ps | awk '/django/{print $1}') bash` in order to enter the Django container. Take to the time to understand this command, don't copy/paste blindly ([docker exec documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)). If this command fails, then check the status of the container with `docker ps`, it might not be up.

`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` will let you run arbitrary commands inside the existing container. Thus, you'll be able to check whatever you want. For instance, using `ls -la`, you'll be able to see if the `Dockerfile` worked as expected. You'll also access have to Django / Gunicorn logs, etc.

Side note, you may want to run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up` without the final `-d` to run containers in the foreground (cf. [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/)): it will be easier to spot any mistake.